# Integral of a continuous function is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Is it true that
$$F(t) = \int_{K}f(x,t)dx$$ is continuous if $f$ is continuous and $K$ is compact? How to prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $K$ compact, then it is dominated by a constant. Then you can use a very famous theorem involving integrals and dominated functions.